Building an Azure IoT SDK C application with linking issues
I have built the azure-iot-sdk-c on Debian. All the samples build and run as expected.
I am now trying to create a portable application with my own Makefile, with all the required Azure libraries inside one libs folder. I am having issues linking to the libraries. My application should simply provision itself on the Azure IoT hub and then send messages.
I have taken the sample code directly from the prov_dev_client_sample into my own source file and my Makefile looks like this :
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

INC = -I./inc -I./inc/c-utility/inc -I./inc/iothub_client/inc -I./inc/umqtt/inc -I./inc/deps/umock-c/inc -I./inc/deps/azure-macro-utils-c/inc -I./inc/deps/azure-macro-utils-c/inc -I./inc/provisioning_client/inc -I./inc/provisioning_client/adapters

LIBS = -L./libs -laziotsharedutil -liothub_client -liothub_client_mqtt_transport -liothub_client_http_transport -lprov_mqtt_transport -luhttp -lprov_device_client -lprov_device_ll_client -liothub_service_client -lumqtt -lprov_auth_client -lprov_http_transport -lhsm_security_client -lumock_c -luamqp -lprovisioning_service_client -lprov_mqtt_ws_transport -lprov_amqp_ws_transport -lprov_amqp_transport -liothub_client_amqp_ws_transport -liothub_client_amqp_transport -lparson -lserializer

GENLIBS = -lm -lcrypto -luuid -lcurl -lpthread

default: client

client.o: client.c  
    $(CC) -c client.c $(INC) -o client.o
    
client: client.o
    $(CC) client.o $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(GENLIBS) -o client 

I am stuck on the following linking issues. I can't include the complete output as it's too big. I would appreciate any help to try and resolve this. Am I missing any libraries so far, or is sequence wrong in the Makefile or something else?
gcc client.o -g -Wall -L./libs -laziotsharedutil -liothub_client -liothub_client_mqtt_transport -liothub_client_http_transport -lprov_mqtt_transport -luhttp -lprov_device_client -lprov_device_ll_client -liothub_service_client -lumqtt -lprov_auth_client -lprov_http_transport -lhsm_security_client -lumock_c -luamqp -lprovisioning_service_client -lprov_mqtt_ws_transport -lprov_amqp_ws_transport -lprov_amqp_transport -liothub_client_amqp_ws_transport -liothub_client_amqp_transport -lparson -lserializer -lm -lcrypto -luuid -lcurl -lpthread -o client 
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub.c.o): in function `IoTHub_Init':
iothub.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `platform_init'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub.c.o): in function `IoTHub_Deinit':
iothub.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `platform_deinit'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `freeHttpWorkerThreadInfo':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `Lock_Deinit'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `garbageCollectorImpl':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_get_head_item'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x175): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_item_get_value'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_get_next_item'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1a8): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_remove'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x297): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x301): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `iothub_ll_message_callback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x405): undefined reference to `VECTOR_push_back'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `iothub_ll_inputmessage_callback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x515): undefined reference to `VECTOR_push_back'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `make_method_calback_queue_context':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x5b8): undefined reference to `STRING_construct'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x633): undefined reference to `BUFFER_create'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x658): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x6ca): undefined reference to `VECTOR_push_back'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x6e7): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x6f7): undefined reference to `BUFFER_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `iothub_ll_connection_status_callback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0xb00): undefined reference to `VECTOR_push_back'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `iothub_ll_event_confirm_callback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0xbb4): undefined reference to `VECTOR_push_back'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `iothub_ll_reported_state_callback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0xc74): undefined reference to `VECTOR_push_back'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `iothub_ll_device_twin_callback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0xe04): undefined reference to `VECTOR_push_back'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `iothub_ll_get_device_twin_async_callback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0xfd7): undefined reference to `VECTOR_push_back'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `invoke_application_command_callback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x10c2): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x10d9): undefined reference to `BUFFER_u_char'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x10f0): undefined reference to `BUFFER_length'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x12a9): undefined reference to `BUFFER_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x12bc): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `dispatch_user_callbacks':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x12e7): undefined reference to `VECTOR_size'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x133e): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1450): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1473): undefined reference to `VECTOR_element'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1657): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x166e): undefined reference to `BUFFER_u_char'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1685): undefined reference to `BUFFER_length'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x179d): undefined reference to `BUFFER_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x17ad): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1813): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x182a): undefined reference to `BUFFER_u_char'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1841): undefined reference to `BUFFER_length'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x188a): undefined reference to `BUFFER_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x189a): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x18f4): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1933): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1a3d): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1a7c): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1bd5): undefined reference to `VECTOR_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `ScheduleWork_Thread_ForMultiplexing':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1c08): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1c21): undefined reference to `VECTOR_move'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1c35): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `ScheduleWork_Thread':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1d24): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1d48): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1d78): undefined reference to `VECTOR_move'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1d9a): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `create_iothub_instance':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x1f9b): undefined reference to `VECTOR_create'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2015): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_create'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2081): undefined reference to `VECTOR_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2209): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2293): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x22f8): undefined reference to `Lock_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2392): undefined reference to `Lock_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x242c): undefined reference to `Lock_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x24ec): undefined reference to `Lock_Deinit'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x24fc): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2553): undefined reference to `VECTOR_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_Destroy':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x29e0): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2a5e): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2b40): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2bb7): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2bd1): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2c39): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_get_head_item'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2c5f): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2c7e): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2cda): undefined reference to `VECTOR_size'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2d0a): undefined reference to `VECTOR_element'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2d3f): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2d4f): undefined reference to `BUFFER_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2e4b): undefined reference to `VECTOR_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2e68): undefined reference to `Lock_Deinit'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SendEventAsync':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x2ff1): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x319e): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_GetSendStatus':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x3229): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x32a7): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SetMessageCallback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x33a2): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x35ec): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SetConnectionStatusCallback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x36e7): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x38e0): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SetRetryPolicy':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x39da): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x3a5a): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_GetRetryPolicy':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x3b55): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x3bd7): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_GetLastMessageReceiveTime':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x3c62): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x3ce0): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SetOption':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x3d7d): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x40a8): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SetDeviceTwinCallback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x41a6): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x439f): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SendReportedState':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x44a2): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x465a): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_GetTwinAsync':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x47f1): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x48de): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SetDeviceMethodCallback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x4ad6): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x4c88): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SetDeviceMethodCallback_Ex':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x4d83): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x4f35): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SubscribeToCommands':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x5030): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x51f2): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_DeviceMethodResponse':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x5289): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x5366): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `startHttpWorkerThread':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x53f8): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x546b): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_add'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x554b): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_remove'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x556f): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `markThreadReadyToBeGarbageCollected':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x5590): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x5604): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `allocateUploadToBlob':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x5729): undefined reference to `mallocAndStrcpy_s'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x578f): undefined reference to `Lock_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SetInputMessageCallback':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x6273): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x631e): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_SendMessageDisposition':
iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x6425): undefined reference to `Lock'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core.c:(.text+0x64ad): undefined reference to `Unlock'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `is_event_equal':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0xaf9): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `is_event_equal_for_match':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0xb68): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_item_get_value'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `device_twin_data_destroy':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0xb98): undefined reference to `CONSTBUFFER_DecRef'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `make_product_info':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0xebe): undefined reference to `platform_get_platform_info'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0xf2d): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0xf4e): undefined reference to `STRING_construct_sprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0xf60): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0xf88): undefined reference to `STRING_construct_sprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0xf98): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_SendComplete':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x106a): undefined reference to `DList_RemoveHeadList'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_ReportedStateComplete':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x1229): undefined reference to `DList_RemoveEntryList'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_GetProductInfo':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x137b): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_GetModelId':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x140f): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_MessageCallbackFromInput':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x1532): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_find'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x155f): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_find'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x15d1): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_item_get_value'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `initialize_iothub_client':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2105): undefined reference to `tickcounter_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x22da): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x25e9): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x27a2): undefined reference to `tickcounter_create'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2930): undefined reference to `tickcounter_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2a2f): undefined reference to `tickcounter_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2a8a): undefined reference to `DList_InitializeListHead'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2a9a): undefined reference to `DList_InitializeListHead'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2aaa): undefined reference to `DList_InitializeListHead'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2c25): undefined reference to `tickcounter_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2c38): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2d76): undefined reference to `tickcounter_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2d89): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `dev_twin_data_create':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x2e5e): undefined reference to `CONSTBUFFER_Create'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `delete_event':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3023): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `delete_event_callback_list':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x30aa): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_foreach'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x30bd): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_CreateFromConnectionString':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x378a): undefined reference to `STRING_construct'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x37fe): undefined reference to `STRING_TOKENIZER_create'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x386b): undefined reference to `STRING_new'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x38d8): undefined reference to `STRING_new'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3945): undefined reference to `STRING_new'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x39b2): undefined reference to `STRING_new'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3a44): undefined reference to `STRING_TOKENIZER_get_next_token'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3ab8): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3af1): undefined reference to `STRING_TOKENIZER_create'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3b78): undefined reference to `STRING_TOKENIZER_get_next_token'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3bdb): undefined reference to `STRING_TOKENIZER_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3bec): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3c11): undefined reference to `STRING_TOKENIZER_get_next_token'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3c74): undefined reference to `STRING_TOKENIZER_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3c85): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3c9c): undefined reference to `STRING_TOKENIZER_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3ccb): undefined reference to `STRING_clone'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3ce2): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3d72): undefined reference to `STRING_clone'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3d89): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3e19): undefined reference to `STRING_clone'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3e30): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3ec0): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x3f68): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x400d): undefined reference to `STRING_clone'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x4024): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x40b0): undefined reference to `STRING_clone'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x4184): undefined reference to `STRING_TOKENIZER_get_next_token'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x43a8): undefined reference to `STRING_c_str'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x442e): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x4441): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x4454): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x4467): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x447a): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o):iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x448d): more undefined references to `STRING_delete' follow
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_CreateFromConnectionString':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x44ec): undefined reference to `STRING_TOKENIZER_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_Destroy':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x479e): undefined reference to `DList_RemoveHeadList'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x47fd): undefined reference to `DList_RemoveHeadList'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x4860): undefined reference to `DList_RemoveHeadList'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x48a4): undefined reference to `tickcounter_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x48ca): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x48dd): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `attach_ms_timesOutAfter':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x494e): undefined reference to `tickcounter_get_current_ms'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_SendEventAsync':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x4cda): undefined reference to `DList_InsertTailList'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `DoTimeouts':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x53e3): undefined reference to `tickcounter_get_current_ms'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x5493): undefined reference to `DList_RemoveEntryList'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_DoWork':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x5597): undefined reference to `DList_RemoveEntryList'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x55b8): undefined reference to `DList_InsertTailList'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_SetOption':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x5c4b): undefined reference to `STRING_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x6055): undefined reference to `STRING_construct'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_SendReportedState':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x6438): undefined reference to `DList_InsertTailList'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `create_event_handler_callback':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x7cee): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_create'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x7d85): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_find'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x7e21): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_item_get_value'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x7e9d): undefined reference to `STRING_construct'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x7fb0): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_add'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `remove_event_unsubscribe_if_needed':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x8087): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_find'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x80fc): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_item_get_value'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x8180): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_remove'
/usr/bin/ld: iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x81e7): undefined reference to `singlylinkedlist_get_head_item'
/usr/bin/ld: ./libs/libiothub_client.a(iothub_client_core_ll.c.o): in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_SetInputMessageCallbackImpl':
iothub_client_core_ll.c:(.text+0x82e8): undefined reference to


This smells like a library-order issue.  The order in which libraries -- especially static libraries -- are presented is significant to the linker.  Undefined symbols within may be resolved only against libraries that appear later on the command line.

@Engineer999 please share the code as well.  are sending c2d messages/telemetry messages to the IOT hub. How you are connecting to the IoT hub? .please share other major and minor details you are trying in step-wise.

@Sampath I've added my code now separately. Basically, I want to provision on the hub and send device to cloud telemetry messages.

@Engineer999 please add in the question not in the answer

@Sampath It won't fit into the question unfortunately

As John said above, this is a library order issue. The library aziotsharedutil is used extensively by the other IoT libraries. Try moving it towards the back.

Here is my source code also :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "iothub.h"
#include "iothub_transport_ll.h"
#include "iothub_device_client.h"

#include "azure_c_shared_utility/shared_util_options.h"
#include "azure_c_shared_utility/http_proxy_io.h"
#include "azure_c_shared_utility/threadapi.h"

#include "azure_prov_client/prov_device_client.h"
#include "azure_prov_client/prov_security_factory.h"

#ifdef SET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES
#include "certs.h"
#endif // SET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES

PROV_DEVICE_TRANSPORT_PROVIDER_FUNCTION prov_transport;
IOTHUB_CLIENT_TRANSPORT_PROVIDER  iothub_transport;

//
// The protocol you wish to use should be uncommented
//
#define SAMPLE_MQTT
//#define SAMPLE_MQTT_OVER_WEBSOCKETS
//#define SAMPLE_AMQP
//#define SAMPLE_AMQP_OVER_WEBSOCKETS
//#define SAMPLE_HTTP

#ifdef SAMPLE_MQTT
#include "iothubtransportmqtt.h"
#include "azure_prov_client/prov_transport_mqtt_client.h"
#endif // SAMPLE_MQTT
#ifdef SAMPLE_MQTT_OVER_WEBSOCKETS
#include "iothubtransportmqtt_websockets.h"
#include "azure_prov_client/prov_transport_mqtt_ws_client.h"
#endif // SAMPLE_MQTT_OVER_WEBSOCKETS
#ifdef SAMPLE_AMQP
#include "iothubtransportamqp.h"
#include "azure_prov_client/prov_transport_amqp_client.h"
#endif // SAMPLE_AMQP
#ifdef SAMPLE_AMQP_OVER_WEBSOCKETS
#include "iothubtransportamqp_websockets.h"
#include "azure_prov_client/prov_transport_amqp_ws_client.h"
#endif // SAMPLE_AMQP_OVER_WEBSOCKETS
#ifdef SAMPLE_HTTP
#include "iothubtransporthttp.h"
#include "azure_prov_client/prov_transport_http_client.h"
#endif // SAMPLE_HTTP

#ifdef SET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES
#include "certs.h"
#endif // SET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES

// This sample is to demostrate iothub reconnection with provisioning and should not
// be confused as production code

MU_DEFINE_ENUM_STRINGS_WITHOUT_INVALID(PROV_DEVICE_RESULT, PROV_DEVICE_RESULT_VALUE);
MU_DEFINE_ENUM_STRINGS_WITHOUT_INVALID(PROV_DEVICE_REG_STATUS, PROV_DEVICE_REG_STATUS_VALUES);

static const char* global_prov_uri = "global.azure-devices-provisioning.net";
static const char* id_scope = "0ne00C8369A";

volatile static bool g_registration_complete = false;
static bool g_use_proxy = false;
static const char* PROXY_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";

#define PROXY_PORT                  8888
#define MESSAGES_TO_SEND            2
#define TIME_BETWEEN_MESSAGES       2

char iot_hub_uri [100];
char device_ID [50];

static void registration_status_callback(PROV_DEVICE_REG_STATUS reg_status, void* user_context)
{
    (void)user_context;
    (void)printf("Provisioning Status: %s\r\n", MU_ENUM_TO_STRING(PROV_DEVICE_REG_STATUS, reg_status));
}

static void register_device_callback(PROV_DEVICE_RESULT register_result, const char* iothub_uri, const char* device_id, void* user_context)
{
    (void)user_context;
    if (register_result == PROV_DEVICE_RESULT_OK)
    {
        (void)printf("\r\nRegistration Information received from service: %s, deviceId: %s\r\n", iothub_uri, device_id);
        strncpy(iot_hub_uri, iothub_uri, sizeof(iot_hub_uri));
        strncpy(device_ID, device_id, sizeof(device_ID));

    }
    else
    {
        (void)printf("\r\nFailure registering device: %s\r\n", MU_ENUM_TO_STRING(PROV_DEVICE_RESULT, register_result));
    }
    g_registration_complete = true;
}

int main(void)
{

#ifdef SAMPLE_MQTT
    prov_transport   = Prov_Device_MQTT_Protocol;
    iothub_transport = MQTT_Protocol;
#endif // SAMPLE_MQTT

    SECURE_DEVICE_TYPE hsm_type;
    //hsm_type = SECURE_DEVICE_TYPE_TPM;
    //hsm_type = SECURE_DEVICE_TYPE_X509;
    hsm_type = SECURE_DEVICE_TYPE_SYMMETRIC_KEY;

    // Used to initialize IoTHub SDK subsystem
    (void)IoTHub_Init();
    (void)prov_dev_security_init(hsm_type);

    // Set the symmetric key if using they auth type
    // If using DPS with an enrollment group, this must the the derived device key from the DPS Primary Key
    // https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/iot-dps/concepts-symmetric-key-attestation?tabs=azure-cli#group-enrollments


    prov_dev_set_symmetric_key_info("test-device", "wN2Pnc2GbodAvjPKSeKViK/Hh0GNyvoYEgPnctR0umI=");

    HTTP_PROXY_OPTIONS http_proxy;
    PROV_DEVICE_TRANSPORT_PROVIDER_FUNCTION prov_transport;

    memset(&http_proxy, 0, sizeof(HTTP_PROXY_OPTIONS));

    // Protocol to USE - HTTP, AMQP, AMQP_WS, MQTT, MQTT_WS
#ifdef SAMPLE_MQTT
    prov_transport = Prov_Device_MQTT_Protocol;
#endif // SAMPLE_MQTT
#ifdef SAMPLE_MQTT_OVER_WEBSOCKETS
    prov_transport = Prov_Device_MQTT_WS_Protocol;
#endif // SAMPLE_MQTT_OVER_WEBSOCKETS
#ifdef SAMPLE_AMQP
    prov_transport = Prov_Device_AMQP_Protocol;
#endif // SAMPLE_AMQP
#ifdef SAMPLE_AMQP_OVER_WEBSOCKETS
    prov_transport = Prov_Device_AMQP_WS_Protocol;
#endif // SAMPLE_AMQP_OVER_WEBSOCKETS
#ifdef SAMPLE_HTTP
    prov_transport = Prov_Device_HTTP_Protocol;
#endif // SAMPLE_HTTP

    printf("Provisioning API Version: %s\r\n", Prov_Device_GetVersionString());

    if (g_use_proxy)
    {
        http_proxy.host_address = PROXY_ADDRESS;
        http_proxy.port = PROXY_PORT;
    }

    PROV_DEVICE_RESULT prov_device_result = PROV_DEVICE_RESULT_ERROR;
    PROV_DEVICE_HANDLE prov_device_handle;


    if ((prov_device_handle = Prov_Device_Create(global_prov_uri, id_scope, prov_transport)) == NULL)
    {
        (void)printf("failed calling Prov_Device_Create\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (http_proxy.host_address != NULL)
        {
            Prov_Device_SetOption(prov_device_handle, OPTION_HTTP_PROXY, &http_proxy);
        }

        //bool traceOn = true;
        //Prov_Device_SetOption(prov_device_handle, PROV_OPTION_LOG_TRACE, &traceOn);
#ifdef SET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES
        // Setting the Trusted Certificate. This is only necessary on systems without
        // built in certificate stores.
        Prov_Device_SetOption(prov_device_handle, OPTION_TRUSTED_CERT, certificates);
#endif // SET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES

        // This option sets the registration ID it overrides the registration ID that is
        // set within the HSM so be cautious if setting this value
        //Prov_Device_SetOption(prov_device_handle, PROV_REGISTRATION_ID, "[REGISTRATION ID]");

        //Prov_Device_SetOption(prov_device_handle, PROV_REGISTRATION_ID, "symm-device-2-ID");

        prov_device_result = Prov_Device_Register_Device(prov_device_handle, register_device_callback, NULL, registration_status_callback, NULL);

        if (prov_device_result == PROV_DEVICE_RESULT_OK)
        {
            (void)printf("\r\nRegistering Device\r\n\r\n");
            do
            {
                ThreadAPI_Sleep(1000);
            } while (!g_registration_complete);
        }
        else
        {
            (void)printf("\r\nRegistering failed with error: %d\r\n\r\n", prov_device_result);
        }

        Prov_Device_Destroy(prov_device_handle);
    }
    prov_dev_security_deinit();

    IOTHUB_DEVICE_CLIENT_HANDLE device_handle;

    if ((device_handle = IoTHubDeviceClient_CreateFromDeviceAuth(iot_hub_uri, device_ID, iothub_transport) ) == NULL)
    {
        printf(("Failed to create IoTHub client from IoT Hub URI %s!\r\n", iot_hub_uri));
    }

    // Free all the sdk subsystem
    IoTHub_Deinit();

    (void)printf("Press enter key to exit:\r\n");
    (void)getchar();

    return 0;
}

